# Mi imagen en Unity no se mueve con C# pero sus coordenadas cambian

Tags: c#, imagen, unity, unity2d

Estoy aprendiendo a mover imagenes en unity usando C#, cuando le doy play me aparece que las coordenadas cambian pero la imagen se mantiene en la misma posicion, el codigo aparentemente funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo mainplayer.cs, es algo basico, no se si tenga que mover algo en el unity para que la imagen logre moverse, al ejecutarlo las coordenadaX y la coordenadaY aumentan

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mainplayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Texture2D Icono;
    public int CoordenadaX;
    public int CoordenadaY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Bienvenido");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CoordenadaX += 10;
        if (CoordenadaX == 500)
        {
            CoordenadaY++;
            CoordenadaX = 0;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Actividad o Inactividad");
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(CoordenadaX, CoordenadaY, 100, 50), Icono);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claramente las coordenadas, es decir, tus variables `CoordenadaX` y `CoordenadaY` están cambiando.

Lo que sucede es que todo [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) se mueve modificando la posición del [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) asociado, cosa que tu código no está haciendo. Hay otras maneras de mover `GameObject` pero esta es la más básica.

Probablemente quieras asignar la posición a las variables que están cambiando, así:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(CoordenadaX, CoordenadaY);
```